# How to add a string from XML file to my java action class? Struts 2 and Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, struts2, javabeans

I am using Struts 2 and Spring for my project. I want to get a string from an XML file on my home/data.xml folder. I have seen the java way of directly accessing the XML file but I did n't want that because there are many dependencies in the classes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the question? Where is the location of the file to be read? Do you want to read values from xml and get that in Java using Spring configuration?

Comment: the location of my file is in my file system, home folder. yes i want a specific string in the Xml file for my java action class. For example:<data>
 <accounts>
     <account id="1">
   <firstName>asdf</firstName>
   <lastName>qwer</lastName>
   <accountNumber>12342344</accountNumber>
  </account>
 </accounts>
</data> In this case I want to get the firstname only for authentication.

Comment: I would suggest you to write your reading logic in your own class, pass the file name through Spring IoC, and get the values from this and inject into your action class.